# Parcelable Android

Tags: android

Preciso fazer o Parcelable desta classe, mas está dando o erro:

> class not found when unmarshalling

Poderiam me ajudar?

Minha classe:

```
    public class Internship implements Parcelable {
        private Enterprise enterprise;
        private int id;
        private String publicationTime;
        private String startDate;
        private String end_date;
        private String requirements;
        private String benefits;
        private int semester;
        private String title;
        private String observation;
        private ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

        public Internship(){

        }

        public Internship(Parcel in){
           this.enterprise = in.readParcelable(Enterprise.class.getClassLoader());
           this.id = in.readInt();
           this.publicationTime = in.readString();
           this.startDate = in.readString();
           this.end_date = in.readString();
           this.requirements = in.readString();
           this.benefits = in.readString();
           this.semester = in.readInt();
           this.title = in.readString();
           this.observation = in.readString();
           in.readList(courses, Course.class.getClassLoader()); 
       }

       public ArrayList<Course> getCourses() {
           return courses;
       }

       public void addCourseToCourses(Course course) {
           this.courses.add(course);
       }

       public Enterprise getEnterprise() {
           return enterprise;
       }

       public void setEnterprise(Enterprise enterprise) {
           this.enterprise = enterprise;
       }

       public int getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(int id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getPublicationTime() {
           return publicationTime;
       }

       public void setPublicationTime(String publication_time) {
           this.publicationTime = publication_time;
       }

       public String getStartDate() {
           return startDate;
       }

       public void setStartDate(String start_date) {
           this.startDate = start_date;
       }

       public String getEnd_date() {
           return end_date;
       }

       public void setEnd_date(String end_date) {
           this.end_date = end_date;
       }

       public String getRequirements() {
           return requirements;
       }

       public void setRequirements(String requirements) {
           this.requirements = requirements;
       }

       public String getBenefits() {
           return benefits;
       }

       public void setBenefits(String benefits) {
           this.benefits = benefits;
       }

       public int getSemester() {
           return semester;
       }

       public void setSemester(int semester) {
           this.semester = semester;
       }

       public String getTitle() {
           return title;
       }

       public void setTitle(String title) {
           this.title = title;
       }

       public String getObservation() {
           return observation;
       }

       public void setObservation(String observation) {
           this.observation = observation;
       }

       public static final Parcelable.Creator<Internship> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Internship>() {
            public Internship createFromParcel(Parcel in){
            return new Internship(in);
       }

       public Internship[] newArray(int size){
            return new Internship[size];
       }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(publicationTime);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(startDate);
        dest.writeString(end_date);
        dest.writeString(requirements);
        dest.writeString(benefits);
        dest.writeInt(semester);
        dest.writeString(observation);
        dest.writeList(courses);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode implementar esse `Parcelable` da seguinte maneira:

```
  public Internship(Parcel in){
       this.enterprise = in.readParcelable(Enterprise.class.getClassLoader());
       this.id = in.readInt();
       this.publicationTime = in.readString();
       this.startDate = in.readString();
       this.end_date = in.readString();
       this.requirements = in.readString();
       this.benefits = in.readString();
       this.semester = in.readInt();
       this.title = in.readString();
       this.observation = in.readString();
         if (courses == null)
        {
          courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
        }
        parcel.readTypedList(courses, Course.CREATOR);//alterado
        this.courses = in.readParcelable(Course.class.getClassLoader());//alterado
        }


     public static final Parcelable.Creator<Internship> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Internship>() {
        public Internship createFromParcel(Parcel in){
        return new Internship(in);
        }

   public Internship[] newArray(int size){
        return new Internship[size];
       }
     };

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(publicationTime);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(startDate);
    dest.writeString(end_date);
    dest.writeString(requirements);
    dest.writeString(benefits);
    dest.writeInt(semester);
    dest.writeString(observation);
    dest.writeTypedList(courses); // alterado
 }
```

Comment: Perfeita a resposta cara, consegui implementar. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Estamos aqui pra isso, @ViníciusVenanciodosSantos